# Не могу понять как правильно реализовать изображение-карту игрока

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Хочу реализовать карту игрока чтобы бот сам рисовал её через pillow. Возникает ошибка.. Помогите исправить код чтобы он был рабочим

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def card(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)

    img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#232529')
    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)[:-10]

    response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    response = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    response = response.convert('RGBA')
    response = response((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIS)

    img.paste(response, (15, 15, 115, 115))

    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name = ctx.author.name 
    tag = ctx.author.descriminator 

    headline = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 20)
    undertext = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 12)

    idraw.text((145, 15), f'{name}#{tag}', font = headline)
    idraw.text((145, 50), f'ID: {ctx.author.id}', font = undertext)

    img.save('user_card.png')

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File(fp = 'user_card.png'))
```

Ошибка:

```
Command raised an exception: UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x045CF7F8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется проблема в том, что  у вас в коде много опечаток :)

Вот что я нашел

- ANTIALIS → ANTIALIAS
- response((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIS) → response.resize()
- descriminator → discriminator

Может еще что упомянуть забыл, но есть еще пара замечаний:

1. `url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)[:-10]` - не совсем понял, зачем вам тут `[:-10]`, так как и без этого все хорошо работает
2. `@client.command(pass_context = True)` - в новых версиях команд дискорда, нет необходимости указывать `pass_context`. Достаточно просто скобок после `command`

**Немного переделал код, вроде работает:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import ImageDraw, ImageFont, Image
import requests
import io

TOKEN = 'TOKENTOKENTOKENTOKENTOKENTOKENTOKENTOKENTOKENTOKEN'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command()
async def card(ctx):

    img = Image.new('RGBA', (400, 200), '#232529')
    url = str(ctx.author.avatar_url)

    response = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    response = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
    response = response.convert('RGBA')
    response = response.resize((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    img.paste(response, (15, 15, 115, 115))


    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    name = ctx.author.name 
    tag = ctx.author.discriminator 

    headline = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 20)
    undertext = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', size = 12)

    idraw.text((145, 15), f'{name}#{tag}', font = headline)
    idraw.text((145, 50), f'ID: {ctx.author.id}', font = undertext)

    img.save('user_card.png')

    await ctx.send(file = discord.File(fp = 'user_card.png'))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

---

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: слушай, как я понял ты не плохо разбираешься в теме с discord-py, не мог бы ты посмотреть мой ещё один вопрос по той теме?

Comment: @Юзер я посмотрел, но там, насколько я понимаю больше идет работа с файлами, чем с дискордом. Тем более, я же не знаю что у вас записано в этом .json-файле, поэтому не могу предположить как с ним работать и в чем ошибка)